# Nonbreakable space for bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

Why do we need to use a nonbreakable space `~` for the bibliography?

For example, in the book "More math into LaTeX" by G. Grätzer, on pp. 47, the following snippet of code is given:

```
\bibitem{eM57a}
Ernest~T. Moynahan,
\emph{Ideals and congruence relations in
lattices.} II,
Magyar Tud. Akad. Mat. Fiz. Oszt. K\"{o}zl.
\textbf{9} (1957), 417--434.
```

As far as I can see, using a `~` for names in the bibliography does not make sense, as names never get so long that they would be broken  - in contrast for references for theorem numbers and the like, where the `2` from `Theorem 2` indeed might end up on the next line, if this was typeset as `Theorem \cite{sometheorem}`.

Comment: I don't know why Grätzer adds that tie, which is pretty useless.

Comment: @egreg Glad to hear that a highly experienced tex.SX user agrees. So you would also code such a `bibitem´ without the `~` ?

Comment: Ties can be useful if there is a long list of authors, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the book "Practical LaTeX" of George Grätzer you can find on page 94 a simular example like that you showed in your question.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{gM12}%
  George~A. Mennuhin, \emph{Universal Algebra},
  University Series in Higher Mathematics, vol.~158,
  D.~Van Nostrand, Princton, 2012.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Here the `vol.~158` and `D.~Van` can make sense because with the usage of `\bibitem` the writer of the document has the control for a good layout.

I teach my students (for didactical reasons) always write a `~` where one do not want to get a line break, if it is useless (`George~A.` a linebreak should not occur) or not.  It is easier to write `~` always than only from time to time where it is needed.

If the bibliography is build via `.bib` file I do not write `~`.

With the following MWE (I doubled the `\bibitem` to have one with `~`, one without)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % try with 10pt and 11pt

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Text~\cite{gM12} Text \cite{gM13} text

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{gM12}%
    George~A. Mennuhin, \emph{Universal Algebra},
    University Series in Higher Mathematics, vol.~158,
    D.~Van Nostrand, Princton, 2012.
  \bibitem{gM13}%
    George A. Mennuhin, \emph{Universal Algebra},
    University Series in Higher Mathematics, vol. 158,
    D. Van Nostrand, Princton, 2012.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I get the resulting pdf:

[image]

Marked with the red arrow you can see an usually unwanted line break between `vol.` and number `158`. With other parameters for `geometry` or fontsize you can get the situation, that a typographic unwanted line break could happen between `D.` and `Van`.  So I think it makes sense writing `~` in bibliographys build with `\bibitem` ...

Comment: You can eassily get unwanted breaks in names as well, as an author *list* can cover multiple lines

Comment: I'm sure it would be possible to find  a pathological combination of a 2-column reference section (IEEE journal use them), a "Surname, Firstname I." format and an author called "Verylongfirstname I. Von Ridiculously-Doublebarrelled" that could break things even so - perhaps in combination with one of those strange citation styles that presents the reader with a long key